# How can I serve CSS files in ejs and express

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I am facing a problem in loading CSS in my app made using express. I have done all the necessary things
correctly like using express.static() to server static file and I know this because when I open view source page and tap on the CSS link I get redirect to my CSS file and it is the same as what I have written so I can't understand why my CSS is not working.

the code is used for serving static files (I use it for css only)
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))`

my CSS link in ejs template

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="css/loginstyle.css">`

NOTE: If the question is unclear then sorry I am new to StackOverflow and I know title is a little bit misleading but StackOverflow would not let me post question so I had to change the tittle